# Expurgar dados inválidos antes de criar um Chave Estrangeira (FK)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou trabalhando com uma base de dados **legado** onde se há 3 tabelas: `Tabela A`, `Tabela B` e `Tabela C` que armazena o relacionamento entre as **Tabelas A** e **B**, entretanto quando o banco foi criado as **Chaves Estrangeiras (FK)** não foram criadas agora se faz necessário a criação das mesmas, porém como não existia esta FK a **Tabela C** (que armazena o relacionamento) esta completamente ***zuada*** já que foram removido registros da Tabela A, Tabela B sem que houve-se a restrição de FK. Como expurgaria os dados da Tabela C que não estão presentes em A e B para poder criar a FK necessária (Ágora ela é imprescindível)?

Exemplo gráfico da situação atual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

em verde a tabela OK, com o passar do tempo os registros das Tabelas A e B foram sendo removidos (Tarja vermelha) e a Tabela C já ***zuada***.

Ambiente:
Banco de dados: SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta fazer um `DELETE` na `Tabela C`, verificando se os `id` que estão sendo usados na tabela `C` não existe mais na `A` ou na `B`.

```sql
DELETE
FROM
    Tabela C 
WHERE
    idTabelaA NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TabelaA) OR 
    idTabelaB NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TabelaB)
```